# Access VBA - Button on Report to show additional information

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report called 'Expenditures' that shows various information about each record (date, amount, type, etc.).  Each record also has a 'Notes' field.

I want to add a button on each line of the report (I've done that part) that will show the Notes for the selected record.  I'm not sure if this would just be running a query, then displaying it, or something else.

All I have right now is a query that shows the Notes field, but when you click the button, it shows the Notes field for all the records since I don't have any criteria yet.

Is this possible? If so, I would appreciate any help!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically reports in access are not 'interactive' (unless you view them in "Report" view).  For example, the button will not be visible on "print preview".

I suggest you add a field to your table that controls the visibility of the field (ShowNotes = Yes/No). That checkbox would be added to the form where you maintain the data.  When running the report you would then add code to the "On Format" event for the details section.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.Notes.Visible = Me.[ShowNotes].Value
End Sub
```

Or, if you are going to the trouble of adding the field to the table, you could adjust your query below the report to show values in the "Notes" field only if the check-box is checked.  (a "no code" solution).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a report 'Invoice List' that displays the summary info about all invoices, and I wanted to have a button on each line to open the report 'Invoice' that displays the full details of just that invoice. In the event properties of the button I added an OnClick event (using the macro builder). This event is OpenReport 'Invoice' and includes a filter with the following condition;

[Invoice_Data]![Invoice_No]=[Reports].[Invoice List].[Invoice_List_Invoice_No].[Value]

The report 'Invoice' has got a query added to its Record Source (Data Tab) property called 'Invoice_Data' which pulls the invoice data from the various tables, the above filter condition then just tells it which individual Invoice No to use when running this query.